# tracks all changes at sharePoint item level to display it in Power PI

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi

I am using SharePoint 2016 , I have a list containing many columns include a status column. I want to link this list to power bi so that power bi can track all changes in that list. sth like , show how many items have a certain status. which user change the status and when.

Comment: Can you outline what you have tried, for example have you tried using the 'SharePoint List' connecter in Power BI Desktop?

Comment: I want to prepare the data to be pulled. first I want to keep track of all changes.how can I achieve this step.

Comment: you'll not be able to keep a track of all changes, you'll need a database for that

Comment: how ? can you share the steps?